# OCL (Object Constraint Language) select, use sum for attribute

Tags: uml, constraints, modeling, ocl

I'm trying to find an **OCL excpression** (calculator), but I'm not sure how to get the sum of the attributes of a collection.

I have a class `Customer` and a class `Orders`. I want to have the sum of all orders of a particular year saved in the `Customer` class, attribute `revenue`. 
`Orders` has attributes 'date_order' and 'amount'.
Given is that year(Date) gives the year of a specific date and `Date.now()` gives the current date.

I found this solution:

```
context Customer::revenue

derive: self.orders -> select(year(datum_order) = (year(Date.now()) – 1)) -> collect(amount) -> sum()
```

I would like to not use collect, but I really don't know how to do this with only the select statement. I assume leaving out collect(amount) and change sum to `amount.sum()` is also not right?

I hope someone can help me with this expression.

Comment: What is the reason for wanting to avoid `select`?

Comment: Because it should not be in my vocabulary yet ;).
But never mind, I can just use it of course.

Comment: Thank you for the solution you found (perhaps for the same assignment? ;), I just needed this!